# Long pressing space key of keyboard to launch my activity

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a transparent activity . I want that whenever the user come across the default soft keyboard (eg: in messaging app while composing) and long presses the space key or any key in the keyboard , it launches my transparent activity . Ofcourse my service will be running behind.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

i think this will do your task

```
protected boolean onLongPress (Keyboard.Key popupKey)
```

It is called when a key is long pressed.

Parameters - popupKey   the key that was long pressed

for further information see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#onLongPress%28android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key%29)